# How to create ADO.Net Entity Data Model (.edmx) without opening diagram

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, edmx, visual-studio-2015, edmx-designer

I'm working on Database-first Entity data model. Due to nature of project there are lots of entities and I've a single .edmx file for that.

Every time I've to regenerate edmx file it takes a lot of time and some amount of time is consumed in loading the diagram in Visual Studio (2015). I don't want Visual Studio to open the diagram automatically as its not useful to me.

Is there any way to regenerate the edmx file without automatically loading diagram in Visual Studio?

I've checked on various sources but couldn't find any way to do it.

Comment: Maybe consider using Code based model with EF reverse poco template instead?

Comment: Thanks @ErikEJ but I don't think if Code based model can be adopted as this a data-intensive product which is being migrated from existing application.

Answer (score 0):

To regenerate, right click on the edmx file and select "Run Custom Tool"

To stop loading the Diagram:

Right-click on the edmx file and click "Open With..."

Then select "Source Code (Text) Editor and then click "Set as Default".

You can change it back to the "ADO.NET Entity Data Model Designer" at a later date by performing the same process.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I tried it several times but no gain in performance. 
1. Run Custom Tool - doesn't update model from database
2. Set as Default - might be negligible performance improvement.